# Does "Docker On Windows" launch a linux virtual machine?

Tags: docker

I'm aware that the old Docker Toolbox uses VirtualBox to run a minimal linux virtual machine for Docker using [`boot2docker`](http://boot2docker.io/) which is a minimal light-weight Linux OS. Now, with the new [**Docker on Windows**](https://www.docker.com/docker-windows) they claim that they use HyperVisor on Windows 10 Pro directly.

Does this mean the **Docker on Windows** package got rid of the Linux virtual machine totally, or is there still a Linux virtual machine being used on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

A container is considered “native”, if it can run directly on the host operating system.

Linux Container - A Linux application that runs in an isolated Linux environment.
This same container can be run on a Windows OS using virtualization to emulate a Linux environment, but the container is still running on Linux.

Windows (Server) Container - A Windows application that runs in an isolated Windows environment.

Docker on Windows to run a Linux container requires virtualization. The available options are:
VirtualBox (Docker Toolbox)
Hyper-V backend (Docker Desktop)
WSL2 backend (Docker Desktop)

The *Container* (and *Docker*) terminology is very confusing, especially with Windows nuances. See [Docker Container in Linux and Windows](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/docker-container-linux-windows/) for an overview with many useful reference links.